# multiple line regex group match

Tags: regex, ms-access, vbscript, match, multiline

I am trying to parse a template format using regex.

Here is a sample

```
Type of Change:                 Modify
Metavance:                      None
AutoSys :                       None
Informatica Migration:          None
FTP Details:                    None
Device/Server:                  DWEIHPRD
DB Objects:                     Delete
                                 ARC_MEDICAL_CLAIM_DETAIL_FK1
DB Name:                        DWEIHPRD
Schema-Table(s):            UTIL
Interface(s):                     IF0515
Reports (RAPS):              None
Ancillary Systems:            None
```

Basically everything is

Field : Data (possibly multiline, as in the DB Objects example above)

```
^(.+?):(.*)
```

is pretty close to doing what I want, except its only grabbing the first line of the DB Objects. If I turn on dotall, then everything gets matched greedy and everything is in the "first field" result.

optimally extra whitespace in both the field and data would be trimmed, but that is not a huge deal if it doesn't happen as part of the regex.

As an added bother, I am having to do this work in access 97 vbscript, so its possibly some of the nicer modern regex features might not be available :(

Comment: no. If there is some other easy to implement in vbscript solution, that is fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: this is an ugly solution, but maybe it will help you. As @anubhava suggested, there may be a non-regex solution. I just don't know VBA well enough to say what it might be.

According to this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1400241x%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) VBScript for Microsoft Office supports lookaheads, lookbehinds and non-capturing (date on the article was 2009), but I would be quite surprised if support goes back as far as Access 97 - though I could be wrong.

Normally, I would use lookaheads, and non-capturing groups for this, but avoided them because they are unlikely to be supported in Office 97. So note that you will just have to ignore capture group 3 (which is only there to test for optional end of line characters on multi-line matches). Note this will only find matches that spread two-lines.

```
^(.+):\s+(.+)(\r\n\s+(.+))*
note this has four capture groups, but you will ignore \3. Use \1, \2, and \4 (four will be empty for single line matches)
```

Explained:

```
^         # beginning of line
(.+):     # capture one or more characters up to a colon
\s+(.+)   # skip past whitespace, then capture characters up to end of line
(         # open a capturing group (to be thrown away. See explanation above)
  \r\n\s+ # peek ahead to see if there are EOL characters followed by whitespace
  (.+)    # if we got this far, capture whatever characters come after the whitespace
)*        # and make this group optional (and you will ignore it anyway)
```